# Why do we need str type? Why not just byte-strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

Python3 has unicode strings (`str`) and `bytes`. We already have bytestring literals and methods.  Why do we need two different types, instead of just byte strings of various encodings?

Comment: That's what a `str` is… a bytestring with encoding, which hides the encoding used internally.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Why do we need to add a new encoding, instead of using a perfectly good one we already have? (https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: You're forgetting memoryview, bytearray, and Unicode (Python2-only). Python has much more than just two types.

Comment: @Hatshepsut: Python doesn't add any new encodings. I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I must've misunderstood your comment. I though you were saying that Python internally uses an additional encoding, hidden by `str`.

Comment: @Hatshepsut, it doesn't, nor does it have a particularly unique way of storing strings internally (unlike say, Swift, which uses grapheme clusters to store Unicode characters).

Comment: @Hatshepsut, I believe either as ASCII, UCS-2, or UTF-32 (note, although UCS-2 and UTF-16 are similar, they are **not** the same), depending on the maximum code point in the string.

Comment: Python uses many encodings for strings. The string object itself tracks which encoding it uses, so you don't need to know. You can even mix and match strings with different encodings freely. All you need to know is that they contain arrays of Unicode code points.

Answer (score 9):

The answer to your question depends on the meaning of the word "need."

We certainly don't need the `str` type in the sense that everything we can compute with the type we can also compute without it (as you know quite well from your well-worded question).

But we can also understand "need" from the point of view of convenience. Isn't it nice to have a `sqrt` function? Or `log` or `exp` or `sin`? You could write these yourself, but why bother? A standard library designer will add functions that are useful and convenient.

It is the same for the language itself. Do we "need" a while loop? Not really, we can use tail-recursive functions. Do we "need" list comprehensions? Tons of things in Python are not primitive. For that matter do we "need" high level languages. [John von Neumann himself once asked "why would you want more than machine language?"](http://www.columbia.edu/cu/computinghistory/index.html)

It is the same with `str` and `bytes`. The type `str`, while not necessary, is a nice, time-saving, convenient thing to have. It gives us an interface as a sequence of characters, so that we can manipulate text character-by-character without:

- us having to write all the encoding and decoding logic ourselves, or
- bloating the string interface with multiple sets of iterators, like `each_byte` and `each_char`.

As you suspect, we *could* have one type which exposes the byte sequence and the character sequence (as Ruby's `String` class does). The Python designers wanted to *separate* those usages into two separate types. You can convert an object of one type into the other very easily. By having two types, they are saying that separation of concerns (and usages) is more important than having fewer built-in types. Ruby makes a different choice.

TL;DR It's a matter of preference in language design: separation of concerns by distinct type rather than by different methods on the same type.

Answer (score 7):

Because bytes should not be considered strings, and strings should not be considered bytes. Python3 gets this right, no matter how jarring this feels to the brand new developer.

In Python 2.6, if I read data from a file, and I passed the "r" flag, the text would be read in the current locale by default, which would be a string, while passing the "rb" flag would create a series of bytes. Indexing the data is entirely different, and methods that take a `str` may be unsure of whether I am using bytes or a str. This gets worse since for ASCII data the two are often synonymous, meaning that code which works in simple test cases or English locales will fail upon encountering non-ASCII characters.

There was therefore a conscious effort to ensure bytes and strings were not identical: that one was a sequence of "dumb bytes", and the other was a Unicode string with the optimal encoding for the data to preserve O(1) indexing (ASCII, UCS-2, or UTF-32, depending on the data used, I believe).

In Python 2, the Unicode string was used to disambiguate text from "dumb bytes", however, `str` was treated as text by many users.

Or, to quote [the Benevolent Dictator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0358/#id4):

> Python's current string objects are overloaded. They serve to hold both sequences of characters and sequences of bytes. This overloading of purpose leads to confusion and bugs. In future versions of Python, string objects will be used for holding character data. The bytes object will fulfil the role of a byte container. Eventually the unicode type will be renamed to str and the old str type will be removed.

**tl;dr version** 
Forcing the separation of `bytes` and `str` forces coders to be conscious of their difference, to short-term dissatisfaction, but better code long-term. It's a conscious choice after years of experience: that forcing you to be conscious of the difference immediately will save you days in a debugger later.

Comment: All very true and a good answer. I've always found, though, that separating bytes and characters, is wonderful and proper and liberating and welcome, and not at all "annoying." What is annoying is the conflating of the two concepts. Python 2's ill-fated attempt to conflate the concepts led to massive annoyances with "ASCII decoding error: ordinal not in range(128)" so it is Python 2, not 3, which is annoying. Python 2 MUST DIE, and the sooner the better. End of rant. :)

Comment: @RayToal, I totally agree, I made the argument that "to the new developer, it is annoying". What was much more annoying for me was the days spent in PDB debugging my conflation of the two once I needed to use that same code in production as a new developer.

Comment: Ah true! So we need a massive cultural shift then so that new developers have no reason to _expect_ that bytes are characters. Perhaps the problem is with those that learn C first? If you start with Python 3, you should be quite comfortable with the difference.

Comment: I also feel tutorials that try to minimize the difference (**cough** *Learn Python the Hard Way*) need to disappear, and routinely damage new developers in the long term (I "Learned" the Hard Way, and have since been blocked by Zedd Shaw on Twitter for pointing out the numerous inaccuracies in what I learned). @RayToal

Comment: Plus 1 just for the first sentence alone

Answer (score 2):

Byte strings with different encodings are *incompatible* with each other, but until Python 3 there was nothing in the language to remind you of this fact. It turns out that mixing different character encodings is a surprisingly common problem in today's world, leading to far too many bugs.

Also it's often just easier to work with whole characters, without having to worry that you just modified a byte that accidentally rendered your 4-byte character into an invalid sequence.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two reasons:

1. the `str` type has an important property "one element = one character".
2. the `str` type does not depend on encoding.

Just imagine how would you implement a simple operation like  reversing a string (`rword = word[::-1]`) if `word` were a bytestring with some encoding.